# SwiftUI: How to get selections from OutlineGroup?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-outlinegroup

`OutlineGroup` is an analogue to `NSOutlineView`. `NSOutlineView` supports single/multiple node selection and we can obtain them by querying on `NSOutlineView`. Though *obtaining* selection on `NSOutlineView` is O(n), but this can be optimized to O(1) if the view tracks selection and provide them in proper interface.

How to obtain selections from `OutlineGroup`? Especially for multiple node selections. I checked out [the manual entry](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup), but couldn't find any mention about selection. What am I missing here?

Comment: Answer from another question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/63786164/246776

Answer (score 2):

[image: Selectable List]
Here is the code.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = Set<FileItem.ID>()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(selection: $selection) {
                    OutlineGroup(data, children: \.children) { item in
                        Text("\(item.description)")
                    }
                    .onTapGesture {
                        print(selection)
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
                .navigationTitle("Files")
                //.toolbar { EditButton() }
                .environment(\.editMode, .constant(.active))
                .onTapGesture {
                    // Walkaround: try how it works without `asyncAfter()`
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05, execute: {
                        print(selection)
                    })
                }
                Text("\(selection.count) selections")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

// Sample data:

struct FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: Self { self }
    var name: String
    var header: String?
    var children: [FileItem]? = nil
    var description: String {
        switch children {
        case nil:
            return " \(name)"
        case .some(let children):
            return children.isEmpty ? " \(name)" : " \(name)"
        }
    }
}

let data =
  FileItem(name: "users", children:
    [FileItem(name: "user1234", children:
                [FileItem(name: "Photos", header: "Header 1", children:
        [FileItem(name: "photo001.jpg", header: "Header 2"),
         FileItem(name: "photo002.jpg")]),
       FileItem(name: "Movies", children:
         [FileItem(name: "movie001.mp4")]),
          FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
      ]),
     FileItem(name: "newuser", children:
       [FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
       ])
    ])

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is not completely finished as it looks. Use direct SwiftUI autogenerated interfaces in Xcode 12 to find updates.

Especially for asked `OutlineGroup` there are several constructors with `selection` parameter, like below:

```
/// Creates a hierarchical list that computes its rows on demand from an
/// underlying collection of identifiable data, optionally allowing users to
/// select multiple rows.
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - data: The identifiable data for computing the list.
///   - selection: A binding to a set that identifies selected rows.
///   - rowContent: A view builder that creates the view for a single row of
///     the list.
@available(iOS 14.0, OSX 10.16, *)
@available(tvOS, unavailable)
@available(watchOS, unavailable)
public init<Data, RowContent>(_ data: Data, children: KeyPath<Data.Element, Data?>, 
    selection: Binding<Set<SelectionValue>>?, @ViewBuilder rowContent: @escaping (Data.Element) -> RowContent) where Content == OutlineGroup<Data, Data.Element.ID, HStack<RowContent>, HStack<RowContent>, DisclosureGroup<HStack<RowContent>, OutlineSubgroupChildren>>, Data : RandomAccessCollection, RowContent : View, Data.Element : Identifiable
```

Comment: I can't find this on autogenerated interfaces. Did you check this on macOS 11 (beta)? I'm still on macOS 10.x

Comment: It seems like `OutlineGroup` need to be a content of a `List`.

Comment: @Eonil, no, I've installed Xcode 12b on macOS 10.15.5

Answer (score 1):

You need to put **NavigationLink**/**Button** for the item which do not have children.

Here is how it could look based on Apple source code.

```
var body: some View {
    OutlineGroup(data, children: \.children) { item in
        Group {
            if item.children == nil {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text("\(item.name)"),
                    label: {
                        Text ("\(item.description)")
                    })
            } else {
                Text ("\(item.description)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The data comes from an Apple [example](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/outlinegroup). Sometimes links gets broken. So, here is source code:

```
struct FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: Self { self }
    var name: String
    var children: [FileItem]? = nil
    var description: String {
        switch (children) {
        case nil:
            return " \(name)"
        case .some(let children):
            return children.count > 0 ? " \(name)" : " \(name)"
        }
    }
}

let data =
    FileItem(name: "users", children:
                [FileItem(name: "user1234", children:
                            [FileItem(name:"Photos", children:
                                        [FileItem(name: "photo001.jpg"),
                                         FileItem(name: "photo002.jpg")]),
                             FileItem(name:"Movies", children:
                                        [FileItem(name: "movie001.mp4")]),
                             FileItem(name:"Documents", children: [])
                            ]),
                 FileItem(name: "newuser", children:
                            [FileItem (name: "Documents", children: [])
                            ])
                ])
```

Comment: How does this make outline group selectable?

Comment: Items which do not have childrens are wrapped in the NaviationLink.

Comment: Does anybody have any solution for that problem? Please post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Using a NavigationLink as the view to represent the children of the tree actually do work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).