# Adding headers to OutlineGroup / DisclosureGroup

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI 2.0, and I need a way to add a header to an `OutlineGroup` or `DisclosureGroup`, similar to headers in `List` sections. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Isn't DisclosureGroup label of what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate `Section`s to create the headers (and, optionally, footers).

[image: Sectioned List]

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Node : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let children: [Node]?
}

struct SectionedOutlineView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $selection) {
            Section(header: Label("Nodes 1", systemImage: "sparkle")) {
                OutlineGroup(nodes1, children: \.children) { node in
                    Label(node.name, systemImage: "shield")
                }
            }

            Section(header: Label("Nodes 2", systemImage: "rosette")) {
                OutlineGroup(nodes2, children: \.children) { node in
                    Label(node.name, systemImage: "folder")
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
    }

    @State var nodes1 = [
        Node(name: "Layer 1", children: [
            Node(name: "Layer 1-1", children: [
                Node(name: "Layer 1-1-1", children: nil),
                Node(name: "Layer 1-1-2", children: nil),
            ]),
            Node(name: "Layer 1-2", children: [
                Node(name: "Layer 1-2-1", children: nil),
                Node(name: "Layer 1-2-2", children: nil),
                Node(name: "Layer 1-2-3", children: nil),
            ]),
            Node(name: "Layer 1-3", children: nil),
        ]),
        Node(name: "Layer 2", children: [
            Node(name: "Layer 2-1", children: [
            ]),
            Node(name: "Layer 2-2", children: [
            ]),
            Node(name: "Layer 2-3", children: [
            ]),
        ])
    ]

    @State var nodes2 = [
        Node(name: "Layer 1", children: [
            Node(name: "Layer 1-1", children: [
                Node(name: "Layer 1-1-1", children: nil),
                Node(name: "Layer 1-1-2", children: nil),
            ]),
            Node(name: "Layer 1-2", children: [
                Node(name: "Layer 1-2-1", children: nil),
                Node(name: "Layer 1-2-2", children: nil),
                Node(name: "Layer 1-2-3", children: nil),
            ]),
            Node(name: "Layer 1-3", children: [
            ]),
        ]),
        Node(name: "Layer 2", children: [
            Node(name: "Layer 2-1", children: [
            ]),
            Node(name: "Layer 2-2", children: [
                Node(name: "Layer 2-2-1", children: nil),
                Node(name: "Layer 2-2-2", children: nil),
                Node(name: "Layer 2-2-3", children: nil),
            ]),
            Node(name: "Layer 2-3", children: [
            ]),
        ])
    ]

    @State var selection = Set<Node.ID>()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: List with headers]

```
import SwiftUI

struct NodeOutlineGroup<Node>: View where Node: Hashable, Node: Identifiable, Node: CustomStringConvertible{
    let node: Node
    let childKeyPath: KeyPath<Node, [Node]?>
    let headerKeyPath: KeyPath<Node, String?>?
    @State var isExpanded: Bool = true

    var body: some View {
        if node[keyPath: childKeyPath] != nil {
            DisclosureGroup(
                isExpanded: $isExpanded,
                content: {
                    if isExpanded {
                        ForEach(node[keyPath: childKeyPath]!) { childNode in
                            NodeOutlineGroup(node: childNode,
                                             childKeyPath: childKeyPath,
                                             headerKeyPath: headerKeyPath,
                                             isExpanded: isExpanded)
                        }
                    }
                },
                label: {
                    section
                })
        } else {
            section
        }
    }
    
    var section: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if let kp = headerKeyPath, let header = node[keyPath: kp] {
                Section(header:
                            HStack {
                                Text(header)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .background(Color.secondary.opacity(0.3))
                ) {
                    Text(node.description)
                }
                
            } else {
                Text(node.description)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NodeOutlineGroup(node: data, childKeyPath: \.children, headerKeyPath: \.header, isExpanded: true)
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

// Sample data
struct FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable, CustomStringConvertible {
    var id: Self { self }
    var name: String
    var header: String?
    var children: [FileItem]? = nil
    var description: String {
        switch children {
        case nil:
            return " \(name)"
        case .some(let children):
            return children.isEmpty ? " \(name)" : " \(name)"
        }
    }
}

let data =
  FileItem(name: "users", children:
    [FileItem(name: "user1234", children:
                [FileItem(name: "Photos", header: "Header 1", children:
        [FileItem(name: "photo001.jpg", header: "Header 2"),
         FileItem(name: "photo002.jpg")]),
       FileItem(name: "Movies", children:
         [FileItem(name: "movie001.mp4")]),
          FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
      ]),
     FileItem(name: "newuser", children:
       [FileItem(name: "Documents", children: [])
       ])
    ])
```